# How to convert AccountId to String

Tags: ink, accountid

- I'm building a dApp and would like to treat the contract address as a String.
- I was able to find a way to convert a String to an AccountId, but no example exists for the reverse case.
- I also tried encoding with "parity-scale-codec" as shown below, but it is not guaranteed to be UTF-8, so it cannot be converted to String.

If anyone knows how to convert please help.

```
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn convert_accountid_to_string(&self, account_id: AccountId) -> Vec<u8> {
            let tmp :Vec<u8> = account_id.encode();
            tmp
        }
```

- I implemented the following as advised, but got some errors and don't know how to work around it,

Source Code:

```
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn convert_accountid_to_string2(&self, account_id: AccountId) -> String {
            let account_id = H256::from(account_id);

            // Convert the AccountId to an SS58 encoded string
            let account_id_string = account_id.to_ss58check();
            account_id_string
        
        }
```

Error Information:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `H256: From<ink::ink_primitives::AccountId>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/shin.takahashi/develop/work/account_id_test/lib.rs:39:41
   |
39 |             let account_id = H256::from(account_id);
   |                              ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<ink::ink_primitives::AccountId>` is not implemented for `H256`
   |                              |
   |                              required by a bound introduced by this call
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_ss58check` found for struct `H256` in the current scope
  --> /Users/shin.takahashi/develop/work/account_id_test/lib.rs:42:48
   |
42 |             let account_id_string = account_id.to_ss58check();
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `H256`
```

Comment: let account_id = H256::from([1u8; 32]);

Comment: `use ink_env::AccountId;
use sp_core::H256;
use core::convert::From;

impl From<AccountId> for H256 {
    fn from(account_id: AccountId) -> Self {
        let mut h256 = H256::default();
        h256.as_mut().copy_from_slice(&account_id[..]);
        h256
    }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about SS58 format (which will be costly operation) and just want a string, then why not convert it to hex string? It will be a very cheap operation.

Add [`hex`](https://crates.io/crates/hex) crate to `Cargo.toml` like this

```
[dependencies]
hex = { version = "0.4.3", default-features = false, features = ["alloc"] }
```

```
#[ink::contract]
mod contracts {
    use ink::{
        prelude::string::String,
    };
    
    // ...

    impl Contracts {
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn account_to_string(&self, account: AccountId) -> String {
            hex::encode(account)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The output will be like this `"d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"`

---

Adding to [kayvan's answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8305/4117) here (I can't post comments yet)

The default ink! [`AccountId` has `AsRef<[u8;32]>`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/c1f14bcc1011a36ed72e6726dafb1efbde5bae4d/crates/primitives/src/types.rs#L28-L66) implementation, you can use that to fix your `H256` conversion error.

```rust
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn convert_accountid_to_string2(&self, account_id: AccountId) -> String {
            // convert to &[u8;32] first
            let account_id: &[u8;32] = account_id.as_ref();
            let account_id = H256::from(account_id);

            // Convert the AccountId to an SS58 encoded string
            let account_id_string = account_id.to_ss58check();
            account_id_string
        
        }
```

**EDIT: This will not work inside ink! (wasm32 target as it needs std), use hex approach if you just want a string**

Comment: Thank you for your help. But your code does not work. I got an error. "error[E0599]: no method named `to_ss58check` found for struct `H256` in the current scope". Do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: This is my test repositry using ink!4.0. https://github.com/realtakahashi/account_id_test

Comment: Hi Takahashi
I've just gone through the `sp_core::crypto` code and it is apparent you cannot use `ss58Codec` trait inside ink! as it requires `std` and ink! (wasm) does not allow that

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/74b2c92066ec3abcb612faa9272f246ae339fab3/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L259C25-L266

As I said in my answer above, if you simply want to convert the `AccountId` to string, use the hex approach, it's much more simple and very efficient computation wise (gas efficient also).

Comment: Hi. Ashutosh! Thanks to you, I was able to implement. I post my code as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert an AccountId to a string using the ss58 crate. First, add the ss58 crate to your Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
[
dependencies
]
ss58 = "0.3.0"
```

Then, you can use the ss58::Ss58 trait to convert an AccountId to a string. Here's an example:

```
use sp_core::crypto::Ss58Codec;
use sp_core::H256;

fn main() {
    // Assuming you have an AccountId instance
    let account_id = H256::from([/* your 32-byte array representing the AccountId */]);

    // Convert the AccountId to an SS58 encoded string
    let account_id_string = account_id.to_ss58check();

    println!("AccountId as a string: {}", account_id_string);
}
```

This will convert the AccountId to an SS58 encoded string, which is the standard format for representing Substrate addresses as strings.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I got some errors. I will include the error information in the question, so could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

- I finally implemented the code below. Make AccountId a string with hex. Then enter that string to restore the AccountId.

```
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn convert_accountid_to_hexstring(&self, account_id: AccountId) -> String {
            hex::encode(account_id)
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn convert_hexstring_to_accountid(&self, hex_string:String) -> Option<AccountId> {
            match hex::decode(hex_string) {
                Ok(value) => {
                    let mut array = [0; 32];
                    let bytes = &value[..array.len()];
                    array.copy_from_slice(bytes);
                    let account_id: AccountId = array.into();
                    return Some(account_id);
                },
                Err(_) => None,
            }
        }
```